# libnss3.so NSS_3.22 libdbus-1.so.3 error visual studio code on SuSE

Tags: visual-studio-code, suse, opensuse-12.2

I have a fresh installation of SuSE 12 SP2.

I installed vs code as per commands mentioned on [here](https://en.opensuse.org/Visual_Studio_Code) under Install heading.

When I try to run vs code using command `code`  I get following error:

> /usr/share/code/bin/../code: /usr/lib64/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.22'
>   not found (required by /usr/share/code/bin/../code)
>   /usr/share/code/bin/../code: /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3: no version
>   information available (required by /usr/share/code/bin/../code)

I am running as root.

PS:

1. As I am root I am giving some other dir path using option --user-data-dir.
2. `zypper in libnss3.so`  gives follwing output :

> Loading repository data...    Reading installed packages...
>   'libnss3.so' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
>   'mozilla-nss-32bit' providing 'libnss3.so' is already installed.
>   Resolving package dependencies...
>
> Nothing to do.

Comment: I tried VScode in OpenSUSE Leap 15 live (XFCE) and it works there.

Comment: I have the following distribution:
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12-SP2"
VERSION_ID="12.2"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP2"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12:sp2"